# jquery Polaroid viewer

Tags: jquery

I am hoping to get a little help. I am a designer by nature, so programming is not my strong suite. With that, I am using this jquery plugin to add some dynamic elements to my site.

A link to the source is here:
http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/creating_a_polaroid_photo_viewer_with_css3_and_jquery.html

My question: I would like for the pictures to remain in a div and not "float all over the page. After playing around with the css, I assume this is accomplished by adding code to the script.js file. What do I need to add to contain the polaroids to a div?

Thanks.

Comment: Clarifying question - do you want the images to have the same behavior, only restricted to one area of the page, instead of the whole entire page?

Comment: yes, what he means is exactly that. having the behaviour of the drag / drop and rotate and everything, but inside a container instead of the full page.

Comment: Yes, Sander, that is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ask the developer of this tutorial if it is possible to contain the polaroids. He wrote a new post on his blog how to accomplish this task. http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/the_polaroid_photo_viewer_non-full_screen.html.

Marco, thank you for the help. Your work is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question.  Make this change in the source file's index.html and see if that is what you're looking for.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:800px;">
... image divs
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I had tried these same attributes before submitting my question, which is why I feel it is more of a modification to the script.js file. With my limited knowledge I could certainly be wrong though. However more help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ah, my above answer works in Google Chrome.  In IE8, open Developer Tools and change Document Mode to Quirks mode and it will work.  I tried adding a comment before the doctype and changing the doctype to force quirks mode for FF, but I couldn't get it to work.  It may have something to do with the -moz and -webkit styles.

Comment: I use a mac running OSX, so my browsers consist of Safari and Firefox. Not to be picky, but if I am going to use this awesome polaroid viewer I would need it to be compatible with all (at least most) browsers. Granted the rotate and drop shadow only work in Safari and Chrome.